# Push dictionary to list via for loop

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I want to push two dictionaries into a list via for loop. I don't get why it is not working. Could you pls help? :)

```
result = {}
results = []
for i in range(count): # Count is 2, 2 different dictionaries
    result.update({
        'workitem_id': str(api_results[i]['workitem_id']),
        'workitem_header': api_results[i]['workitem_header'],
        'workitem_desc': api_results[i]['workitem_desc'],
        'workitem_duration': str(api_results[i]['workitem_duration'])})
    print(result) # Shows the two different dictionaries
    results.append(result) 

print(results) # Shows the list of two dictionaries, but the list contains the last dictionary for 2 times. 

Output print(result): {Dictionary 1} , {Dictionary 2}
Output print(results): [{Dictionary 2} , {Dictionary 2}]
```

The expected output of print(results):

```
[{Dictionary 1}, {Dictionary 2}]
```

Comment: Declare `result = {}` inside the loop.

Comment: You constantly update the *same* dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   results = []
   for i in range(count): #->Count is 2, 2 different dictionaries
      result = {
            'workitem_id' :str(api_results[i]['workitem_id']),
            'workitem_header':api_results[i]['workitem_header'],
            'workitem_desc':api_results[i]['workitem_desc'],
            'workitem_duration':str(api_results[i] ['workitem_duration'])}
      print(result) 
      results.append(result) 

   print(results)
```

Comment: Stupid me. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

During the second iteration, the .update method will update the first dictionary in the list. This is because it the two dictionary point to the same reference.

A similar example would be:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a[0] = 'this value is changed in b as well'
print(b)
#['this value is changed in b as well', 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that we're not just using a more straightforward `for` loop?

```
results = []
for x in api_results: 
    result = {
        'workitem_id': str(x['workitem_id']),
        'workitem_header': x['workitem_header'],
        'workitem_desc': x['workitem_desc'],
        'workitem_duration': str(x['workitem_duration'])
    }
    results.append(result) 

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
dictionaries = [  # Let this be the list of dictionaries you have (in your api response?)
    {
        'workitem_id': 1,
        'workitem_header': 'header1',
        'workitem_desc': 'description2',
        'workitem_duration': 'duration2'
    },
    {
        'workitem_id': 2,
        'workitem_header': 'header2',
        'workitem_desc': 'description2',
        'workitem_duration': 'duration2'
    }
]

results = []
for dictionary in dictionaries:
    results.append(dictionary)

print(results)
```